# SELECT the customer who has ordered the greatest quantity of Products?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to make query to find the Customer who has ordered the greatest quantity of Products from the following table!

```
mysql> select * from ORDERS;
+---------+---------+------------+-----+
| CUSTNUM | PRODNUM | DATE       | QTY |
+---------+---------+------------+-----+
|  125216 |    2323 | 2016-03-21 |   2 |
|  136101 |    2357 | 2016-03-21 |   5 |
|  136101 |    2357 | 2016-10-12 |   1 |
|  136101 |    2357 | 2016-11-25 |   5 |
|  136101 |    3737 | 2016-10-12 |  10 |
|  136101 |    9193 | 2016-11-25 |   5 |
|  182764 |    2357 | 2015-03-21 |  12 |
|  182764 |    2357 | 2016-05-12 |  10 |
|  212836 |    3737 | 2015-09-16 |   6 |
|  455566 |    4143 | 2016-02-09 |  10 |
|  455566 |    4143 | 2016-05-12 |  10 |
+---------+---------+------------+-----+
```

expected result

```
+-------------+------------------+
| CUSTNUM     | quantity_ordered |
+-------------+------------------+
| 136101      |               26 |
+-------------+------------------+
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: This is elementary knowledge about MySQL ... `-1`

Comment: it's easy for you maybe, but I'm trying since 4 hours with no luck

Comment: `SELECT *,MAX(QTY) FROM ORDERS`

Comment: @J.Alzaibak Add the expected result

Comment: @J.Alzaibak jophap's answer should work for you.Do the sum by grouping it on the basis of CUSTNUM andorder in reverse order,then limit the result to 1.

Comment: @FlashThunder: who decides what is elementary? You?... +1

Comment: @Jibin Balachandran Thanks, yes it works

Comment: Another question, how to find who has ordered the greatest quantity of
Products in 2015

Comment: @J.Alzaibak You don't have a track of year in your database. If you have, then its possible. If not.. sorry, you will have to add the year column into your table and then proceed.

Comment: @Jibin Balachandran the DATE column is already exist in the table, sorry but I'm doing this as an assignment for the uni, the time is tight and I didn't have enough time to read the whole subject guide.

Comment: @mauro as You can see, not only me.

Comment: I don't see any 'trying' here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use group by clause.

For more info,
Please refer some [tutorials](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/)

Or read the [official docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html)

```
SELECT  CUSTNUM, SUM(QTY) s FROM ORDERS GROUP BY CUSTNUM 
ORDER BY s DESC LIMIT 1
```

[SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fe9faa/12)